# Error Correcting Code and Graph Theory

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, coding-theory

I am currently in an introductory graph theory class, and we are supposed to give a short presentation by the end of the semester.

Recently, I've learned (a very small amount) about error correcting codes. Specifically, I looked at one basic example where there is a chooser and an asker. The chooser picks a number, 0-15, and when he is asked questions, he can lie up to 1 time. The asker has 7 questions to determine what the number is and where/if a lie was told.

I have a feeling that such a problem could be solved using a minimum vertex cover of a graph, but Im not sure. My question is if anyone could point me towards an arXiv paper or has any other advice for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you can get a scheme of questions using the Hamming code of length 7 (=number of questions), 16 codewords (or 4 payload bits to contain the identity of the chooser's pick) that is capable of correcting a single error (=can recover froma single lie).